# Referencing libraries in PyCharm when installed through Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, libraries

Our first semester C++ course requires us to develop an intelligent chatbot for which I have been trying to follow tech with tim's youtube tutorial.

Now, for a long time, I couldn't activate conda environment in the cmd as shown in the video. I was told by a student to write the command in the Anaconda Prompt. I installed all libraries through Anaconda Prompt.

Now, I was using PyCharm and copy pasted the code into it. The libraries when imported are shown to be unreferenced.

I have launched Jupyter via Anaconda Navigator and don't know how to make the same files (as shown in the video) in the Jupyter.

Is there a way that I could link Anaconda to PyCharm? Alternatively can someone guide me as to how I can make .json and separate files in the Jupyter Notebook?

Video linked:
https://youtu.be/wypVcNIH6D4

Answer (score 0):

To link anaconda with pycharm:
[Configure a Conda virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html)
Alternatively you can also do this:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**When using anaconda with pycharm you need to make sure you choosed the right python interpreter when running the script:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]